# Can I compare emmeans for a linear model at any given value of covariate?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I have the following model:

```
ABC<-lmer(A~Ta+MR+mb+group*Acl + (1|ID), data=groups)
```

where Ta, MR and mb are linear covariates.

I want to do a pairwise comparison of emmeans for an interaction.

```
EMMs<-emmeans(ABC, ~group*Acl)

pairs(EMMs, simple = "Acl")
```

I would like to know if it is possible to specify that I would like to compare emmeans at Ta = 40?

I remember that it was possible in SPSS.

Comment: I answered your email of the same question before you posted this. What was wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how the website is posting these messages but I wrote first here and only then found your address and wrote you. I thank you for answer and I am sorry that I forgot to remove the question posted here.

For others who would be interested in the help I got, here is the answer I received from Russ:

Yes. This is easily done:

```
EMMs <- emmeans(ABC, ~ group*Acl, at = list(Ta = 40))
```

(Without the `at` part, the mean of `Ta` is used.)

In general, most arguments to `ref_grid` or `summary` may also be used in **`emmeans`**. See `vignette("basics", "emmeans")` and in particular the part about modifying the reference grid.

Russ

Once again thank you for help,
Michal